# Reading a csv file with string input and convert it to a list

Tags: r, csv

I have string data saved to a csv file.

An example of data is this:

```
col_name,
TextA TextB,
TextC TextD,
```

I try to read the csv using `read.csv()`

When I read the csv I take `numeric` instead of the `string` values. I found this because I don't have the values into quotation marks it doesn't recognized them as string.

Is there and way to handle it in order to take a final result like this:

```
"TextA", "TextB", "TextC", "TextD"
```

Comment: `strsplit` and `unlist`.

Comment: @alistaire thank you. But how about the read of string into without quation marks?

Comment: It's not an issue for `read.csv` (or `read_csv`, `fread`, etc.), because the quotes are superfluous unless you've got commas in your strings. It _would_ be an issue for `read.table`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file is named `test.csv` you can import it with:

```
df <- read.csv('~/Downloads/test.csv',sep=',',header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

where you set the argument `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` to import `col_name` as string. Using `strsplit` and unlisting the resulting list will give you the elements.

```
> unlist(strsplit(df[,1],' '))
[1] "TextA" "TextB" "TextC" "TextD"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly read it with `scan` to create a `vector`

```
v1 <- sub(",", "", scan("text.csv", sep=" ", what = "", quiet=TRUE)[-1])
v1
#[1] "TextA" "TextB" "TextC" "TextD"
```